# There is to be a mistake in the for cycle

Tags: c

> *For some reason this cycle doesn't stop, without the else it doesn't even print the first line and I dont't know how to fix it*

```
    for(int i = 0; prime <= sqrt(rest); ++i) {
        printf("%d", i);
        if (primes[i] == 1) {
            prime = primes[i];
            printf("%d", prime);
            while (rest % prime == 0) {
                rest = rest / prime;
                rep++;
            }
            if (rep == 1) {
                printf("%d", i);
                print++;
            } else if (rep > 1) {
                printf("%d^%d", prime, rep);
                print++;
            }
            if (rest != 1 && print != 0) {
                printf(" x ");
            } else if (print != 0) {
                printf("\n");
            }
            rep = 0;
            print = 0;
        }else{
            printf("WTF\n%d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (rest > 1) {
        printf("%lld\n", rest);
    } else{
        printf("WTF\n");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's time you [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Most importantly, learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code, line by line, while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: The value of `prime` is changed only once, when `primes[i] == 1` and remains unchanged afterwards. How did you expect your cycle to stop then? How many `1`s do you have in your `primes` array?

Comment: Thanks, primes is a list of 0 and 1 (eratosthenes sieve) so that every prime is 1 and its number is the prime (this part is correct)

Comment: Note that if you want output to appear, you have to make sure that you include a newline at the end of the printing — `printf("%d\n", i)` for example.  You also need to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We need to see how you've declared and initialized variables such as the `primes` array.

Comment: Well will do next time. I was almost sure the mistake was something primitive in this cycle

Answer (score 0):

You aren't ever changing the value of prime, which is what your condition is set to stop because of, so if it never changes, it will never stop. Maybe what you meant was prime instead of i in the beginning of your for loop?

Comment: Primes is a list full of 1 and 0 so the value should be changing during every cycle

Comment: @Michallv Also, you need to change it from ++i to i++

Comment: @JoelBanks: What's the reasoning behind your "`++i` to `i++`" comment?  Both work in the context of the increment clause of a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains an endless while: `while (rest % prime == 0) {...}`.

Once rest hit 0, this will always be true, and you keep dividing rest by prime, but `0/prime = 0`, so it keeps going forever.

The same is true for `prime = 1`, which is your assigned value - `rest%1 = 0`, every single time, and `rest/1 = rest`, and so on, forever.

Answer (score 0):

So the mistake I made was this: **prime = primes[i];**, if I use **prime = i;** instead everything works just as it should, I think I made it because I wasn't used to use a list like that where for value you use number of it. Thanks everyone for help